# How do you assign a keyboard shortcut or hotkey in sketchbook pro?

Tags: applescript, autodesk

I'm using Sketchbook pro for mac, [the documentation](http://desktop-help.sketchbook.com/hotkey-shortcuts/) that states: "Many of the tools found in the lagoon and menus have assigned hotkeys. You can also check out the [Preferences window](http://desktop-help.sketchbook.com/resetting-preferences/) for a list of them or to remap a tool." However, the link they provide does not give information about how to remap commands.

So trying to switch gears and use hotkeys instead, now [the documentation](http://desktop-help.sketchbook.com/?s=remap+a+tool&submit=Search) describes a method of assigned hotkeys; however, this doesn't work and nothing happens. Also mysteriously the documentation shows the lagoon with the ability for hotkeys however on my desktop this isn't what I see (see figure below)
[image]

Ultimately my goal is to assign commands to my tablet, literally I just want to assign the `r` key to the rectangle tool instead of the ruler as shown. The problem is that on my Wacom I can only use keystrokes and as it is there is no keystroke for the rectangle command, so frustrating.
[image]

It seems like it would be so simple to just "assign keyboard shortcuts in sketchbook pro" but I can't find a single example of it actually happening, I only find references to it being possible, like for example the [end of this video](http://www.sketchbook.com/blog/press-the-button-sketchbook-wacom-express-keys/) see image below:

[image]

I don't mind trying to figure out how to use Applescript but I can't find any information on how to talk to sketchbook with applescript. Frustratingly there is an interface to run Applescripts...but no information about how to write applescript to interact with sketchbook commands, see figure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about applescript, so I hope someone else can help.

**You cannot set your own shortcuts inside of SketchBook.**
 [You can only select from the list provided.](https://support.sketchbook.com/hc/en-us/articles/209672388-Autodesk-SketchBook-Desktop-Hotkey-and-Shortcut-List-)

In your screen-cap the context of that video is setting your Wacom tablet buttons to Sketchbook hotkeys. That end slide is attempting to communicate that you can use our suggestions (which are listed in the video) or make your own configuration from the available hotkey list. It's not meant to say that you can create your own custom hotkeys.

What are you using the rectangle so much for?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, man this is so disappointing. I'm using sketchbook to draw up outline and coding examples (we use a lot of boxes in programing :) )

Comment: @mbigras Why not create a brush that is boxes, or copy and paste a box and use the 'v' key to transform it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding AppleScript, I've checked via Autodesk Support and they replied they currently do not support it.

The fact that you see your script appearing in "Sketchbook Pro > Services" is a MacOS feature, it doesn't necessary mean Sketchbook knows about it.